# How do I make xset -b work on the LXDE login screen?

Tags: autostart, login-manager, xset

I'm using the boring old LXDE login screen:

[image: Grey bar at the top, with a keyboard picker, little accessibility icon, date, and power button. A background is visible, with a rectangle containing a user icon, a dropdown for a username and a password input box. Below this is a plain "Log in" button.]
<sub>(source: [linuxandubuntu.com](https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/uploads/2/1/1/5/21152474/lubuntu-login-screen_orig.jpg))</sub>

I often hit the wrong few keys for my username or password, backspace them by spamming the relevant key, and then upset everybody in the room because a loud beeping ensues. However, I want the `pcspkr` kernel module to remain. Beeping music is desired; it's just error beeps that are not.

My solution for the login session is to get in the habit of running:

```
xset -b
xflux -l 0.01032 -g -0.00471
xrickroll --random -m 5m -M 7.5h
```

etc. whenever I start my session. But this still doesn't fix the issue on the login screen. For some reason, even though I ran `sudo chmod a+x /etc/X11/Xsession.d/*`, it still isn't running my `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/stop-that-darned-beep` shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
xset -b
```

(Or, at least, it doesn't seem to.)

How can I make `xset -b` function properly when I start my computer? (Ideally, I'd also like the other stuff to run, but I'm fine with those not applying to the login screen and just being in my `~/.xsessionrc`.)